# BDD Framework - Can't Remember Which One Had HTML Integration

Tags: ruby, testing, frameworks, bdd, web-frameworks

I remember learning about a framework when BDD was first getting a lot of attention. This framework had the concept of using the rows or cells of an HTML table to document and run tests/features. So, I'm thinking there was an engine that would walk the cells/rows of the table "executing" each one, and perhaps recording the result. This could also serve as your report of the testing results.

Can someone point me in the right direction for what this framework was? or the ecosystem it came out of? I thought it was related to Ruby gems or concepts but I may be wrong on that.

I'm in interested in recycling some of the ideas that were used in that project / framework.

Comment: I think that's "cucumber", but not sure. https://www.baeldung.com/cucumber-data-tables ?

Comment: I found that too. But the way I remember hearing about it... the test would literally go inside a <td> inside a <tr> in html. And the outcome would be a report that non-technical could understand.